# What is the most up to date production version of mysqli ?

Tags: mysqli

Tough to figure out if I have an up to date version of mysqli or not. 
I use this in a web page :

```
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
printf("MYSQLi Client library version: %s<br>\n", mysqli_get_client_info());
```

The output is :

```
MYSQLi Client library version: mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $
```

Well that is all well and nice .. but my MySQL rev is 5.5.30 base on this :

```
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to ";
// print the MySQL server version
printf("MySQL server version: %s<br>\n", mysql_get_server_info());
```

Which results in :

```
Connected to MySQL server version: 5.5.30
```

Should I expect to see a mysqli rev of 5.5.x or am I wrong?

Any insight would be helpful.

This is Apache 2.4.4 and PHP 5.4.12 if that helps :

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php --version 
PHP 5.4.12 (cli) (built: Feb 25 2013 19:25:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

$ /usr/local/bin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.4 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 28 2013 10:46:58
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysqli extension has been built using a MySQL distribution which version was different from your (MySQL) server version:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

You'll notice the output refers to MYSQLi *Client* library version.

To obtain the version of your server distribution, you can execute the following query using the same PHP version of PHP and mysqli extension:
`SELECT @@version;`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'my_secret_password...');
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT @@version;');

print_r($result->fetch_array());
```

Comment: brilliant ... that results in : Array ( [0] => 5.5.30 [@@version] => 5.5.30 )